# Select html element inside jQuery object

Tags: jquery

If I have:

```
<div id="foo">
  Hello!
  <div class="bar">
  </bar>
</div>
```

And:

```
var some = $("#foo");
```

One way to select the *.bar* div inside *#foo* is:

```
$(some.attr('id') + ' .bar')
```

But this is dirty. Is there a clean way to select the *.bar* div inside *some*?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

*Code*

```
$("#foo").find('.bar'); // some.find('.bar');
```

OR

You can also use [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

> Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```
$("#foo").children('.bar'); // some.children('.bar');
```

Note: The `.children()` method differs from `.find()` in that `.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree while `.find()` can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var bar = $('#foo .bar');
```

This will select the elements having `bar` class which are inside of `#foo` element.

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/

Or

```
var bar = some.find('.bar');
```

This will search for all the elements having class `bar` inside of `some` i.e. `#foo`.

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple to do:

```
var some = $("#foo");

some.find(".bar");
```